# Windows Remote Desktop only works for initial connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Server is Windows 10 Pro. version 1511 build 10586.589 
Client is Windows 10 Home. version 1607 build 14393.187

The first time server boots up and I connect, everything runs smooth.

When I disconnect the server seems to be pertaining changes made by client such as *resolution, removed wallpaper and numlock status.*

After that, **I am unable to connect until I reboot the server**. I get the black screen on connect for a while then it fails.

Another thing I noticed is that on initial connect which works, I get loading message "Other User" with Server's background color, but after that I get the same loading message with broken loader (not animated) and client's background color.

I'm using remote desktop to connect to my pc from laptop, hence the user is always signed in.

I force my connection to use slowest setting (modem) to optimize speed.

When I work on server directly and leave, I lock the screen with win+L and when I work remotely I disconnect with either X on the bar or win->power->disconnect (which seems to yield same result).

Comment: From the Remote Desktop Connection screen before you connect to the server via RDP go to the **`Local Resources`** tab **Local devices and resources** and UNcheck the **Printers** option, and then connect and see if your issue still occurs. Test the **`Experience`** tab **Persistent bitmap caching** setting being off, and then connecting. For the "Speed" setting pick **LAN** for highest setting as well.

Comment: I've tried each and all of those fixes and they do not help much. Sometimes it works (mostly if i reconnect within minutes) and most times it does as in question. My current workaround is using teamviewer to restart computer if not working.....

Comment: if you run `winver`+`enter` what are the version and OS build numbers you see for both client and server? You are RDP'ing into a Windows 10 "Home" edition as the server?

Comment: Sorry, the server is Pro. version 1511 build 10586.589 and client is Home. ver 1607 build 14393.187

Comment: Not exactly sure but it seems like having visual studio open increases the likelihood of this problem. Without it open, problem still exists but frequency is noticeably lower.

Comment: If you're already using teamviewer why not just use teamviewer? In addition you're missing the actual windows name. By the build numbers I'd guess it's Windows 10? What's the message if it fails? Do you see anything on the "Server" while you try to connect? Maybe a popup that asks for confirmation?

Comment: Are you using a domain or workgroup, Microsoft account, or local account.

Comment: I am using local account

Comment: I can confirm the *Other User* display. Even though I use the same Microsoft account on both OSes. I do not however have the problem you're describing! So your issue may be unrelated to the *Other User* thing!